# echo vs file_put_contents using preg_match_all

Tags: php, preg-match-all

```
<?php

$start_date = "20111101";
$todays_date = date('Ymd');

$html = file_get_contents("http://online.wsj.com/mdc/public/page/2_3021-tradingdiary2-{$start_date}.html?mod=mdc_pastcalendar");

preg_match_all(
'#<td style="text-align:left;padding-top:18px;" valign="bottom" class="colhead">(.*?)</td>#',
    $html,
    $EXCHANGE, 
    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);  

preg_match_all(
'#<td class="num">(\d.\d\d)</td>#',
    $html,
    $TRIN, 
    PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);  

    echo "{$EXCHANGE[0][0]},    \r";
    echo "TRIN : {$TRIN[0][0]}, \r";
    echo "{$EXCHANGE[0][1]},    \r";
    echo "TRIN : {$TRIN[0][1]}, \r";
    echo "{$EXCHANGE[0][2]},    \r";
    echo "TRIN : {$TRIN[0][2]}, \r";
    echo "{$EXCHANGE[0][3]},    \r";
    echo "TRIN : {$TRIN[0][3]}, \r";

// write this to a file
$WSJData = 'WJSData.csv';
$WriteMe = "{$TRIN[0][0]}, {$TRIN[0][1]}, {$TRIN[0][2]},  {$TRIN[0][3]}";   

file_put_contents($WSJData, $WriteMe );

?>
```

Why is the output in WSJData.csv different from the echo output?  Why do I get the text I removed with the preg_match_all function in my CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write the result of some `echo` calls to a file, use:

```
ob_start(create_function('$a','file_put_contents(FILENAME,$a); return $a;'));
echo ...
echo ...
...
echo ...
ob_end_flush();
```

This will ensure that what is printed is what goes in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it seems to me that you have some other error in your script.  I reduced it to "the simplest program that works" to reproduce the error.  Here is what I got:

```
<?php

  $TRIN = array( array("E0","E1","E2","E3") );

  echo "TRIN : {$TRIN[0][0]} / ";
  echo "TRIN : {$TRIN[0][1]} / ";
  echo "TRIN : {$TRIN[0][2]} / ";
  echo "TRIN : {$TRIN[0][3]} \n";

  // write this to a file
  $WSJData = 'WJSData.csv';
  $WriteMe = "{$TRIN[0][0]}, {$TRIN[0][1]}, {$TRIN[0][2]}, {$TRIN[0][3]}";   

  file_put_contents($WSJData, $WriteMe );

  echo file_get_contents($WSJData);
```

And the output is:

```
$ php test.php
TRIN : E0 / TRIN : E1 / TRIN : E2 / TRIN : E3
E0, E1, E2, E3
```

The first line of output is from the echoes.  The second is from "file_get_contents".
The substitution works fine.  Indeed, it occurs when assigning the variables, not when echoing or saving to the file.

BTW, I would recommend using \n instead of \r.  The second one will not advance a line, but overwrite the current one (just in the console as it would in the printer), and I suspect that that's not what you wanted.